# How to prevent data being sent to the database if fields are empty?

Tags: php

How would I go about not sending the data to the database if the some of the fields are left empty? Right as of now, if a field is empty on the form, the database is replacing whatever was in the field with blank data

UPDATE: Forgot to mention, it doesn't matter if the some of the fields are left blank, that should be allowed.

My code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['eventname'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['eventvenue'] , $_POST['eventtime'], $_POST['eventcost'])){

$eventname = ($_POST['eventname']);
$eventdate = ($_POST['date']);
$eventtime = ($_POST['eventtime']) . ":00";
$eventvenue = ($_POST['eventvenue']);
$eventcost = ($_POST['eventcost']);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE event set event_name = '" . $eventname . "', event_date = '" . $eventdate . "', event_time = '" . $eventtime . "', event_venue = '" . $eventvenue ."', event_cost = '" . $eventcost ."'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `!empty($variable)` instead of `isset($variable)` (you have to use `!empty($a) && !empty($b)` though.)

Comment: Trivial stuff. (Answered ^.^.^.^.^)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good luck with values such as `"0"` then.

Comment: And please don't use mysql_*-functions, this way your code is a security risk. Use e.g. PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Good luck to "moi"? @Jack It's not "my" code ;-P and take it up with `h2ooooooo` ;-)

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['var'])){ // let it die();'}` Falls into `C.O.W.` code category.

Comment: @OP: As per your edit *"UPDATE: Forgot to mention, it doesn't matter if the some of the fields are left blank, that should be allowed."* Your title is contradicting itself.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not really, if the fields are filled in, then send them. But if the fields are not filled in, then don't as per my code

Comment: Maybe using a [`ternary operation`](http://us1.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) ?

Comment: By the way, you're contradicting yourself again. *"UPDATE: Forgot to mention, it doesn't matter if the some of the fields are left blank, that should be allowed."* and in your comment above *"Not really, if the fields are filled in, then send them. But if the fields are not filled in, then don't as per my code"* @user3144564 You need to clarify this a tad more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like This

```
$query= "UPDATE event set ":

If(isset($var1)){
$query.= " var1=".$var1;
}else if (isset($var2)){

$query.= " var2=".$var2;
}
```

and so forth and then

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read on PHP's function `empty()`

[empty() on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/empty)

Example usage:

```
if(empty($eventname))
{
    echo "You have not set event name";
} else {
    mysqli_query(...);
}
```

As said on comments, do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use either [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).

Comment: My guess: "And please don't use mysql_*-functions, this way your code is a security risk. Use e.g. PDO (php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead."

Comment: Be careful using `empty()` - the number zero (float, integer, or string) is considered empty. If that's what you want, use it. Otherwise check for the specific empty values you are looking for. E.g. `if ($var === null || $var === '')`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php); it builds the update statement based on whether the field is empty (zero length) or not.

Afterwards, the prepared statement is executed.

```
$updates = [];
$parameters = [];

if (strlen($_POST['eventname'])) {
    $updates[] = 'event_name = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST['eventname'];
}

// ...

if (strlen($_POST['eventtime'])) {
    $updates[] = "event_time = ?";
    $parameters[] = $_POST[$field] . ':00';
}

if ($updates) {
    $sql = sprintf('UPDATE event SET %s WHERE xxx', join(',', $updates));
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
}
```